# The most time-efficient way to set slippage before swapping

Tags: transactions, python, instructions

I have the following python code to perform a swap on RAYDIUM:

```
def make_swap_instruction(
        self,
        amount_in: int,
        token_account_in: PublicKey,
        token_account_out: PublicKey,
        accounts: dict,
        serum_program_id=SERUM_PROGRAM_ID,
    ) -> TransactionInstruction:
        print("Making a swap instruction...")
        keys = [
            AccountMeta(pubkey=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["amm_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["authority"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False
            ),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["open_orders"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True
            ),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["target_orders"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True
            ),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["base_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True
            ),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["quote_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True
            ),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=serum_program_id, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["market_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True
            ),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["bids"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["asks"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["event_queue"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True
            ),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["market_base_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True
            ),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["market_quote_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True
            ),
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=accounts["market_authority"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False
            ),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=token_account_in, is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=token_account_out, is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=self.owner.pubkey(), is_signer=True, is_writable=False),
        ]
        print("Finished making, building SWAP LAYOUT...")
        data = SWAP_LAYOUT.build(
            dict(instruction=9, amount_in=int(amount_in), min_amount_out=0)
        )
        return TransactionInstruction(
            accounts=keys, program_id=AMM_PROGRAM_ID, data=data
        )
```

It is my understanding that the min_amount_out parameter in my SWAP_LAYOUT can be changed to set slippage. Since I have it at 0, I think my slippage is effectively 100%.

I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on what some efficient ways to set slippage might be. At the moment, all I can think to do is fetch the current price, and calculate how many tokens I should get back after adjusting for slippage. If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated and I believe a value-add to the community since there doesn't seem to be much on this forum in Python or on slippage.

Comment: I know you're probably using Openbook even though you wrote `SERUM_PROGRAM_ID` in your code, but for anyone reading this, **do not use that program**. Its upgrade key may have been compromised in the FTX hack. Please migrate to the [community fork](https://github.com/openbook-dex/program).